# Getting File not found exception while downloading file from an URL

Tags: android, url, xls, filenotfoundexception

I have a url from which I have to download a xls file. I am posting encoded data and the response will be an xls file. But I am not sure How to download this xls file to my external storage. When I run the network call I got a
`java.io.FileNotFoundException`

and it says

`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference`

I have no Idea how to get the response as a file. Here is my code.

```
try{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data=URLEncoder.encode("job_id","UTF-8")
                +"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(responseText),"UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("m_id","UTF-8")+"="
                +URLEncoder.encode(logedinUserId,"UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("start","UTF-8")+"="
                +URLEncoder.encode(start,"UTF-8");
        data+="&"+URLEncoder.encode("end","UTF-8")+"="
                +URLEncoder.encode(endDate,"UTF-8");

        Log.e("data",""+data);

        String text="";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try{

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url=new URL("url here");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;

            // Read Server Response
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }


            text=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception ex)

        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                reader.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        Log.e("response x",""+text);


    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you debugged your code ? maybe your url is not returning anything and that's why you are getting file not found or null exception ?

Comment: Yes. I have tested it with postman.

Comment: so you have the url working fine ? is it have the file ?

Comment: Yes. It have the file

Comment: can you tell me if it's being downloaded or not ? if yes then it is not being saved to your given path

Comment: It is not getting downloaded.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if your are able to download your file or not ? It's just a basic code for downloading files and you will have to made small changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you have to put the process of downloading in **asyncTask** so that your **UI thread** doesn't gets blocked. Then try this code it will help you download the file.

```
  private class FetchFileURlFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        onCreateDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        String path = "";
        int responseCode = 0;
        StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
            if (f_url[0] != null && !f_url[0].equals(""))
                f_url[0] = f_url[0].replace("your url");


            URL obj = new URL(f_url[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)
                    obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println("Response : -- " + response.toString());

           //              path = connection.getInputStream().toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return response != null ? response.toString() : null;
 //            return path;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        progressDialogForDownload.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String fileURL) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        if (progressDialogForDownload.isShowing() && progressDialogForDownload != null) {
            progressDialogForDownload.dismiss();
            progressDialogForDownload = null;
        }

       // you can open your file using intents or whatever you want to use.
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            Log.d("", "onButtonClickView: " + fileURL);
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.